# Session flash messages are not working in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, session

Since I updated my Laravel version to 7.4, the session flash messages stopped working in Views.

Here is what a part of my code looks like:
Web.php

```
Route::middleware(['web'])->group(function () {

 Route::middleware(['permission:super_user'])->group(function () {

  Route::get('/get/{id}', 'TestController@show');
  Route::post('/set/{id}', 'TestController@update');

 });

});
```

Controller Methods:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

    $message = new stdClass();
    $message->type = 'success';
    $message->text = "Updated successfully!" ;
    session()->flash('message', $message);
    return Redirect::back();

}

public function show(Request $request, $id){

   return view('pages.account')

}
```

Session data is there but flash messages are getting lost somewhere between redirection, not sure where exactly. I tried several solutions like session reflash, removing the web from middleware but it didn't work. Any leads?

Edit:
I found out that session flash exist in this method. Which means app redirect erasing it?

```
function back($status = 302, $headers = [], $fallback = false)
{
    dd(session());
    return app('redirect')->back($status, $headers, $fallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.
In controller method:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

    $message = new stdClass();
    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Updated successfully!');
}
```

In blade file do this:

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
         {{ session()->get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but no luck. It seems like data is getting lost somewhere in middleware, but not sure where exactly.

Comment: Check whether you are reaching in update function when you hit the request?

Comment: In the update, the flash message is there, however after redirect back there isn't any flash message in the get method.

Comment: Please update your question with blade file.

Comment: I found out the session flash exist in this method. Which means app redirect erasing it? any solution?
`function back($status = 302, $headers = [], $fallback = false)
    {
        return app('redirect')->back($status, $headers, $fallback);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try using with() method.

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'IT WORKS!');
```

Then in blade file you can view it as

```
 @if(session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('message') }}
    </div>
 @endif
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but no luck. It seems like data is getting lost somewhere in middleware, but not sure where exactly.

Comment: try it without middleware

Comment: I found out the session flash exist in this method. Which means app redirect erasing it? any solution?
`function back($status = 302, $headers = [], $fallback = false)
    {
        return app('redirect')->back($status, $headers, $fallback);
    }`